# Ejecutar migracion de lumen usando docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, lumen

Tengo un archivo ´docker-compose.yml´ donde tengo: MYSQL y php separados en contenedores.

Entro en el contenedor con php, para ejecutar el comando ´php artisan migrate´, en primera instancia me dice que falta el driver pdo_mysql, ese lo pude solucionar, el error que no he podido solucionar es el que dice ´***SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused***´

Dejo aqui mi ´.yml´ para ver si me falta algo o estoy fallando en algo.

```
version: '2'
services:
  composer:
    container_name: wallet-project-composer
    image: composer
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  database:
    container_name: wallet-project-database
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  rest:
    container_name: wallet-project-rest
    image: php:7.2
    working_dir: /app
    command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 ./api/public/index.php
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: wallet-project-phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
volumes: 
  db_data:
```

> Todo funciona de maravilla, el unico problema es ese.

Comment: Si no entendí mal, dices que al levantar los contenedores desde el compose te va bien, pero al entrar en un contenedor para ejecutar una migración no. Supongo que se debe a que los parámetros para la conexión a la base de datos han de estar en variables de entorno. Cuando levantas los contenedores con compose, estas variables de entorno están especificadas en el `.yml` (ej: `PMA_HOST`,   `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`) pero cuando lanzas docker desde línea de comandos debes especificarlas con la opción `-E`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la ip en DB_HOST es correcta? Revisa ésta en tu .env y en database.php... 
Ahí va la ip del host virtual... puedes ver la ip del host virtual con docker inspect:

Según tu cliente de docker será:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

ó:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container_name_or_id
```

Un saludo

Comment: Si, era el tema del ip, muchisimas gracias.